# Displaying shortcode content inside custom field without images

Tags: custom-field, shortcode

I need to be able to display different shortcodes inside custom fields.

I have [found a method](http://pastebin.com/MkA97GMe) that almost works perfect,  but since that uses `get_content`, it also shows the main featured image of the page.
After the image that's output, the correct content that the shortcode outputs is displayed correctly. How can I stop the image from being output in the first place?

I'm using css to hide it, but would rather not have it output at all.  I've tried using [this other method](http://bavotasan.com/2009/removing-images-from-a-wordpress-post/) which used `get_the_content` instead, and that doesn't work.
The shortcode content doesn't even show at all with that method.

I also found this:

```
echo preg_replace("/\< *[img][^\>]*[.]*\>/i","",get_the_content(),1);
```

Does anyone know how to make that filter work for me with the code I'm using (shown in the pastebin link).

Answer (score 0):

No need to deal with the content, use the `do_shortcode` function directly on your metadata:

```
echo do_shortcode( $your_meta_data );
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, but that is how I normally use my short codes in my custom template pages, but this time I will need to be able to use different short codes on numerous pages, and will need to be able to do this in the pages backend. Not by editing my templates everytime.

Comment: How does it differ from the method you posted? You're just running your meta data through this function rather than applying content filters. You don't have to hardcode the shortcode into the template.

Comment: In other words, when I use the method that you posted, the only thing that is output is the actual words, [my custom shortcode text shows]  in my page, and not the content that the short code should be outputting.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, does this happen with all shortcodes?

Comment: No, short codes work fine on their own, but when trying to insert a short code inside a custom field, I have to use the method I posted on Pastebin. It works, but I just need it to not output the featured image along with it.

Comment: No, I meant when you run the output of get_post_meta through do_shortcode.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried a few other short codes, and just the text will output.

Comment: Very strange, I've done this many times without issue. I'm travelling at the moment so can't test further, but you really shouldnt have to be doing backflips with filtering images and such, this is exactly the case do_shortcode is for.

Comment: Well I really appreciate you trying to help out! If anything else comes to mind when you get back home, I'd be very greatful to hear from you.